# IONIC - Task 'cdvBuildDebug' not found in root project 'android'

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic3

I am getting issue while trying to generate android build

> Task 'cdvBuildDebug' not found in root project 'android'.

Please find below my ionic cordova information

```
cli packages: (/usr/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
Cordova Platforms  : MyApplication android 7.0.0 browser 5.0.3 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.11.1
npm               : 5.6.0 
OS                : Linux 4.13
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : /home/user/Android/Sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Let me know what's wrong with it

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got a work around to this

simply change buildscript in  /android/build.gradle to this

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools"
            }
        }
 }
```